# Application breaks with System.FormatException(not correct input type?)

Tags: c#, input, io, console, console-application

Im making a treegenerator just for training and im taking input from the console splitting it into an array but while trying to split i get an error saying  System.FormatException(not correct input type)

```
Console.WriteLine("Input Number of branches, treefoot, and branch char");
string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int nb = int.Parse(input[1]);
char tf = char.Parse(input[2]);
char bc = char.Parse(input[3]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index 0 is not an `int` in a string, but text in a `string`.

You also got your indices wrong, use `0,1,2`

```
int nb;
bool ok = int.TryParse(input[0], out nb); // ok is true if parsing succeeded
char tf = char.Parse(input[1]);
char bc = char.Parse(input[2]);
```

You should use `int.tryParse()` to see if the `int` parsing succeeded.

Comment: Thank you so much... It seems to work now when i changed to getting the right data from the right place in the array... Stupid me >.<